# About rename upload images in windows live writer

Tags: asp.net, windows-live-writer

I have visited [Hanselman's blog entry](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode55NotABlogALocalXMLRPCMetaWebLogEndpointThatLiesToWindowsLiveWriter.aspx) and set the upload path to

```
 <add key="LocalPublishPath" value="D:\LocalPublishPath"/>
```

But I do not want to use the path that live writer generated.Is there a way to generate folder and filename with datetime.  Example:

```
Windows live writer generated:   D:\LocalPublishPath\WPF_1212F\1_2.jpg
I would like to                  D:\LocalPublishPath\2013101\2013101XXX.jpg
```

And insert into Windows live writer editor with "http://images.XXX.com/LocalPublishPath/2013101/2013101XXX.jpg"

Sorry for my bad english! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Have solved this problem.Check out NewMediaObject method!